# .net 6 api Redirect page cannot be found

Tags: c#, api, rest, .net-6.0

I'm creating and testing my first api, using visual studio .net 6 core and EF core.  Right now I'm just trying to make sure I have everything functioning.  I have a single controller, and I want to redirect to an html page that gives general API usage info.  When I run the debugger and the browser opens to `https://localhost:xxxx` I append /api/values to the end and this gets handled by my controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    public ValuesController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    // GET: api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get() //was return type IEnumerable<string>
    {
        //return new string[] { _env.ContentRootPath, _env.WebRootPath }; //<- WebRootPath returns as null
        return Redirect("../Index.html");

    }
    //other stuff removed for brevity, just calling the above get function
}
```

In my code base directory I have the Index.html file created, and set to copy with a publish.  But I can't get the redirect to this page to work.

The error I get is:

```
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:xxxx/api/Index.html
HTTP ERROR 404
```

When I open Index.html from the file browser it renders properly in Chrome.

I have tried using `Index.html`, `/Index.html`, and `../Index.html` in the redirect call all with the same error, though from different locations.

When I ran with the string array return I see that my ContentRootPath is the path to my project root (where Index.html exists), and that WebRootPath = null.

In launchSettings.json the applicationURL is listed a couple of times.  The first is in iiSettings and given as `http://localhost:xxxxx` (does not seem to be used) and the second in profiles and given as `https://localhost:xxxx;http://localhost:yyyy` (I use the https port and getting the redirect in the controller to work, because the address bar shows `localhost:xxxx/api/Index.html` but the page is the error text above.

I have created a folder `api` in the project and put a copy of `Index.html` in there, still with the same error.

Here is my Program.cs app initialization:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

How do I serve up a static page from my api?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for some reason my googling got better after I posted this question.  If anyone is looking here for a similar problem, I found the solution [here](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-webapi-return-html/).

Simply return a ContentResult object:

```
return new ContentResult
{
    Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"./Index.html"),
    ContentType = "text/html"
}; //new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
```

ControllerBase has a Content() method that will do this for you as well, but what I have above is working within my `public ActionResult Get()` method.

Comment: Would it make sense to close your question as a duplicate of the one you linked?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I suppose that makes sense, but does the duplicate include similar questions on other sites? Usually I see duplicates pointing to another question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectToAction("Directory");
```

You can try doing this, it will throw you directly to the Index page